# Storage listener not working on changing the document.domain to subdomain

Tags: javascript

Am trying to listen for the localstorage change. I have added the eventlistener for storage change like follows.
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e){console.log('ls - ', e.key)});
I am aware that the storage listener will work only when the localstorage is set from another frame or window. Am aware that the listener will not work if we are setting the localstorage from the same window where we have the listener. I have added the listener in www.xyz.com/home.html and setting the local storage in www.xyz.com/menu.html. The listener is not working because am setting the document.domain to 'xyz.com' in www.xyz.com/home.html. Even i tried modifying the document.domain for www.xyz.com/menu.html to 'xyz.com' still facing the same issue.

can somebody help me explaining why the listeners are not working when the document.domain got modified to subdomain.

Eg: www.xyz.com is the location.hostname. Modified document.domain = 'xyz.com'

Answer (score 0):

Open the website www.google.co.in

Set the event listener for storage from console

```
function storageChange(evt)
{
    alert(' key  '+evt.key);
    alert('old value '+evt.oldValue);
    alert('new value '+evt.newValue);
}

window.addEventListener('storage', storageChange, false);
```

Listener will be attached after this action.

open the same domain in new tab.
set the document.domain = "google.co.in" --> it is subdomain of www.google.co.in

now change the local storage value in subdomain tab.

Alert will be fired from original window since the listener is already attached for the local storage change.

Comment: Hi Annoji, Thanks for the response. Actually the reverse is not working for me. Am adding the listener on the modified domain tab. Trying to set the localstorage from the new tab whose document.domain is not modified,